# Infinite Loop in Javascript Neural Net?

Tags: javascript, neural-network

So, I was coding a JavaScript Neural Network for a project. You can look at all of the source code below. However, the code keeps throwing an infinite loop. I debugged my program only to discover that there is something wrong with my loop at the "optimize" property. Honestly, I see nothing wrong with the loop

How can I fix it so that a loop like this is not thrown?

Also, after a few iterations of the neural network, it throws "NaN" for some reason. Can someone please fix this and explain why?

(Don't mind all of my horrible ML practices please. However, remind me if they contribute to the infinite loop)

EDIT: The infinite loop problem is fixed. I just need someone to improve my derivative function since it keeps returning NaN

Thanks. Now, here is the source code:

```
// I will make a single layer feed-forward Javascript neural network

var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var y = [5.2, 7.6, 2.3, 4.5, 3, 9, 10, 10.1, 10.2];
// Pretty much, I'll be doing my computations on a toy dataset

//Time to create a neural network object with three main components: predict, error, and optimize
// "predict" pretty much fits the dataset to the equation y = mx + b and then tries placing a new value of x in the equation to predict a value
// "error" returns how much "wrong" the neural network is in making predictions
// "optimize" conducts gradient descent to fix the error at hand

// Initializing some base values for m and b to be soon improved. 
var m = 1;
var b = 2;

function derivative(f) {
   var h = 0.001;
   return function(x) { return (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2 * h); };
} // Imagine going on a mountain and trying to see the shortest number of steps to get down. This is what the derivative here will do to do umerical optimization

var neural = {
  predict: function(m, x, b) {
    return m * x + b; // pretty much write out the equation. time to now define the error
  },

  error: function(y, m, x, b) {
    var error = 0;
    for (i=0;i < x.length;i++) {
      var pred = neural.predict(m, x[i], b); // Checking again for the equation results to see how wrong they are
      zed = y[i] - pred;
      error += zed;
    return error; // Pretty much this computes the difference between the predict amount and the actual amount befire
    }

  },

  optimize: function(iter, rate, m, b, x, y) { // In this step, we compute the do a "gradient descent" by subtracting the derivative
    for (i=0;i<iter;i++){ // We have training iterations, since a few times can't work
    console.log(neural.error(y, m, x, b).toString());
      m = m - derivative(neural.error(y, m, x, b)) * rate;
      b = b - derivative(neural.error(y, m, x, b)) * rate; // Don't make the learning rate too high/low pl0x
    }
  }

}; 

var net = neural.optimize(10, 0.01, m, b, x, y);
```

Comment: Is `return error;` meant to be *inside* the for loop?

Comment: Well, it makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the counter `i` is global. If you inline your functions, they'd look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  }
}
```

I think you see the issue.

Use `for (var i...` rather than `for (i...`

---

Another problem is that `derivative` returns a *function*, not a number.

The line `m = m - derivative(neural.error(y, m, x, b)) * rate;`

looks more like this:

`m = m - function(){...} * rate;`

This always results in `m` being `NaN`.

Make `derivative` return a value not a function.

---

As mentioned in my earlier comment, I think `return error` should be *outside* the for loop in `error()`.

Comment: True. I just need help on the derivative function